# Is there any way to create a RESW resource in a .NET Standard library?

Tags: wpf, uwp, resources

This is getting really troublesome.  In VS2017, I'm trying to move to UWP and .NET Standard and keep running into roadblocks.  My projects are all fairly large and I have a common set of strings across several projects.  Things like labels for forms and error messages.  I'm also developing in both WPF and UWP, so I'm trying to find some commonality.  It appears that .NET Standard works well for both for most everything except resource strings.  If I try and access a RESX file from UWP, I get a message saying the constructor is protected.  I tried to move to a RESW file, but the .NET Standard libraries don't seem to want to create the PRI file for me.

Comment: did you follow the instructions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest

Comment: Yes.  Please help me understand (1) how I can reference a Universal Windows library from a .NET Standard library (all my view models are stored in .NET Standard Libraries) or (2) how those instructions apply to a .NET Standard project.  I can't seem to create RESW resources in .NET Standard.

Comment: let me direct you to this post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236741/why-did-microsoft-dropped-the-resx-model-for-resw-in-windows-store-applications

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer here. unless you came up with an idea with some code

Comment: How are you trying to access the RESX file? You shouldn't create an instance of it.